# Rails: How to use find_or_create_by in my nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

**Models:** I have a `Company` model that `has_many` `Tasks`. Each `Task` `has_one` `Employee`.

`Task` model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base     
  belongs_to :company       
  has_one :employee,    dependent: :destroy 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee   

  validates_associated :noteholder 
end
```

`Employee` model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :task  

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } 
end
```

**Form:** I created a nested form for `Task` that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` the `Employee` model. The form has an `Employee`  `name` field with an `autocomplete` function that loads all `Company.employees`.

`_form.html.erb` form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@task) do |f| %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :employee do |employee| %>
      <%= employee.input :name, input_html: { data: { autocomplete_source: @employees.pluck(:name).to_json } } %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Save' %>

<% end %>
```

This saves a new record for each employee, regardless of whether or not an employee with that name exists

**Desired behaviour:**
If the user fills in a new `Employee` the model should create a new record, whereas  if it would provide an existing `Employee` name, it should not.

**My attempt:** I thought the `find_or_create_by` method would be useful here, but have had no success with implementing it.

**Question:** How do I correctly set up my model sothat the `Employee` model only saves a new employee if the employee `name` does not yet exist?

Comment: what is the behaviour of the form now? does it create any object at all? could you post the code for the form in your question?

Comment: See the simple form code above, which now saves a new record for each employee, regardless of whether or not an employee with that name exists